# Return text from tags where outermost HTML tags applies to all text nodes within - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text

I have paragraphs of text that might be like this:

```
<p>
   <span style='font-family:arial'>
      Some text
   </span>
</p>
```

or

```
<p>
   <strong>
      Some more text
   <strong>
</p>
```

or

```
<p>
   <strong>
      <em>
         Yet more text
      </em>
   </strong>
</p>
```

However many nested tags there are, I'm able to get just the text, simply using `$('p').text()`. The problem is when `<br>` pops up in the middle. In that case, whatever tag the text is in gets broken up. So for example, this:

```
<p>
  <strong>
     Some more text
  </strong>
</p>
```

will turn into this:

```
<p>
  <strong>
     Some 
  </strong>
  <br />
  <strong>
     more text
  </strong>
</p>
```

So you see, there are now 2 text nodes in the `<strong>` tag, not just one. What I want to do is to get just the text with it's original parent tags, with `<br>` treated as just another text node, but without `<br>`-induced-tag-split-up intrusion. For example, given the 2-node HTML above, I just want a function that returns this:

```
<p>
  <strong>
     Some 
     <br />
     more text
  </strong>
</p>
```

That would be fine for a few given formats, but there could different types of HTML nesting that I need to retain (such as `<p><strong><em>` or `<p><em><strong>` or `<p><strong><span>` and so on.

### Edit

Rather than getting lost in loops, I suppose the easiest way is to get the `$('p').html()` and simply chop away all tags around `<br>`? On the left there of `<br>` would be closing tags, on the right there would be opening tags. Would there be regex solution for this then?

Comment: Why no vanilla JS `yourEl.innerHTML`?

Comment: I can get that, but that won't return the text after chopping away the tags around <br />.

Comment: use `.html()` instead of `.text()`? I don't understand why you're referring to `<br>` as a "text node".

Comment: Why not? `.innerHTML` should get you a normal string, so I would say `var innerstring = yourEl.innerHTML;` and then process the result as a String.

Comment: I tried `var $thepara = $myel.children('p'); console.log("innterhtml: " + $thepara.innerHTML);` but it said `undefined`.

Comment: I said 'Vanilla JS', so no jQuery. Try accessing that paragraph without jQuery, jQuery objects probably have no `.innerHTML` property, because they provide the `.html()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. find each `<br>` within a `<p>`
2. for each of those `<br>` elements, compare the names of the immediately preceding and following elements
3. if their names are equal, move the `<br>` and the contents of the following element into the preceding element
4. remove the now empty following element

This:

```
$("p").clone().find("br").each(function() {
  var $this = $(this), $prev = $this.prev(), $next = $this.next();
  if ( $prev.length && $prev.prop("nodeName") === $next.prop("nodeName") ) {
    $prev.append( $this, $next.contents() );
    $next.remove();
  }
}).end().each(function () {
    console.log( $(this).html() );
});
```

<sup>*(Note that I use `clone()` to avoid modifying the original.)*</sup>

When applied to

```
<p>
  <strong>
     Some 
  </strong>
  <br />
  <strong>
     more text
  </strong>
</p>
```

writes this to the console

```
<strong>
   Some 
<br>
   more text
</strong>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tomalak/y3hSp/

---

Here is an iterative approach that collapses adjacent nodes that are separated by `<br>`, in form of a jQuery plugin:

```
$.fn.extend({
    collapseBreaks: function () {
        return this.each(function () {
            var done = false;

            while (!done) {
                done = true;

                $(this).find("br").each(function() {
                    var $this = $(this), 
                        $prev = $this.prev(), 
                        $next = $this.next();

                    if ( 
                        $prev.length 
                        && $prev.prop("nodeName") === $next.prop("nodeName") 
                    ) {
                        $prev.append( $this, $next.contents() );
                        $next.remove();
                        done = false;
                    }
                });       
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Use as

```
$("p").collapseBreaks();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tomalak/FJFgk/3/

Comment: Wow thank you - this is exactly what I meant! However it's missing one important issue. As I said in my third example in the question and in the part just before the Edit, tags could be nested (any number of times). So I tried the fiddle with the following text: `<p><strong><em>Some</em></strong> <br /><strong><em>text</em></strong>` but the `<em>` tag got split and only `<strong>` was retained.

Comment: You could just run the code multiple times, unwinding one nesting level at a time. Select `$("br")` instead of `$("p br")` and keep going as long as the modifications occur.

Comment: I do get that but I haven't yet managed to wrap my mind around the `.end()` function and chaining together. I tried  `while($(this).prev().length && $(this).next().length)` to your fiddle but that wasn't right.

Comment: `end()` restores the list of selected elements to a previous state: Assume `$("p")` selects 5 `<p>` then `$("p").find("br")` may select 20 `<br>`. `$("p").find("br").end()` will select the original 5 `<p>` again, but you have the chance to do something with the `<br>` in-between.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on `end()`. I've tried a few variations but still no luck :( , here's my fork: http://jsfiddle.net/FJFgk/

Comment: Compare this: http://jsfiddle.net/Tomalak/FJFgk/2/ (and the same thing as a jQuery plugin: http://jsfiddle.net/Tomalak/FJFgk/3/)

Comment: Thank you so much this works exactly, I've spent 2 days on this problem! Yes the plugin's much better - I'll be using this.

Comment: Glad I could help. Be sure to take the time to understand the concepts involved. Don't just copy and paste it. :)

Comment: added an edit to the "if" condition to accommodate for text with more than 3 lines, where two `<br>`s would end up side by side and also get removed.

Comment: Seems like your suggested edit was declined by the community. Maybe it's smarter if you update the fiddle instead, I'll incorporate it in my answer myself.

Comment: I'm not sure that's right... I'd rather do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/Tomalak/FJFgk/5/

Comment: but the intention was not to remove the BRs, it was to retain them and only remove other tags around them, while keeping all the text in the outermost tags. (outermost tags being the initial ones before the BRs came to split them up).

Answer (score 1):

So, what about:

```
var innerString = thatPFromYourQuestion.innerHTML;
innerString = innerString.replace("<.*>", "");
```

That should replace every tag with an empty string, returning all the text inside.

I think I misunderstood your question. If you just want literally what is in that paragraph, `.innerHTML` will do exactly that. If you want the `<BR />` chopped of, you should use a slightly different version of that `replace()` call:

```
innerString = innerString.replace("<br>", "");
```